# How to merge a branch to main branch in Github?

Tags: git, github

I have my code on my local computer.
I created a github repository.
I wanted to upload my local code to this remote github repository.
This is what I did on terminal:

1. I went to the directory of my code from terminal

Then I type:

```
>git init
>git add .
>git commit -m "First commit"
>git remote add origin https://github.com/usergithub/repository_name.git
```

Then I went to my github repository and I saw a new branch:

[image]

So I click on the green button to make a pull request:

[image]

But there is nothing there I can do to merge these 2 branches?

How can I merge the branch to my main project?

I tried different stuff from the terminal:

```
git push --force origin main
```

But I get this error message:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/usergithub/repository_name.git'
```

Comment: Is there anything on `main` to merge with? Or is it the default empty branch github provides? In the latter case, you don't need to merge, just rename one of your two branches to the other.

Comment: The error you get on push is because you don't have a local `main` to push. You could overwrite remote `main` with `git push -f origin master:main` though, but remote `main` branch's contents would be lost (not a problem if it's empty of course). And you would still have a discrepancy, with a remote `main` and a local `master`. You'd better settle on either name and delete the other one.

Comment: @RomainValeri it is an empty default main branch

Comment: What name do you intend to use for your branch? If you prefer `master`, just delete the other with `git push origin :main`. If you prefer `main`, rename your local master with `git branch -m master main` then push it normally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hope the `master` branch contains all of your pushed changes
Steps to merge your branch

1. git checkout `main`
2. git merge `master`
3. git push origin `main`

Now `master` is merged in `main` branch and `main` branch contains all the changes of master branch.

Or you can go to `Pull Request` tab and click on the `Pull request` you have created then scroll down you'll able to see the `Merge Pull Request` Button.
On clicking that button it will merge your branch into `main` branch.

Comment: using `master` as an alias for a branch doesn't seems to be a pretty good idea ..

Comment: Yes, we do not merge master on any other branch. But I've answered according to question.

Answer (score 0):

In this order using Terminal or Command Prompt,

`git checkout main` switch to main branch

`git pull origin main` grab latest updates from main branch

`git merge master` merge master branch to your main branch

`git push origin main` push your changes to main

For easier route, you can download Github Desktop app, add your repo into the app and do all the fetch, commit, push and even PULL REQUEST to merge the branch to the main brach.

FYI, naming your other branch `master` is not recommended and it will making it difficult to distinguish your `main` (your main branch) and `master` (other branch). Github has changed its naming from `master` to `main` instead to avoid unpleasant term.